# Perl referencing and deferencing hash values when passing to subroutine?

Tags: perl, hash, reference, subroutine, dereference

I've been banging my head over this issue for about 5 hours now, I'm really frustrated and need some assistance.

I'm writing a Perl script that pulls jobs out of a MySQL table and then preforms various database admin tasks. The current task is "creating databases". The script successfully creates the database(s), but when I got to generating the config file for PHP developers it blows up.

I believe it is an issue with referencing and dereferencing variables, but I'm not quite sure what exactly is happening. I think after this function call, something happens to 
$$result{'databaseName'}. This is how I get result: `$result = $select->fetchrow_hashref()`

Here is my function call, and the function implementation:

Function call (line 127):

```
generateConfig($$result{'databaseName'}, $newPassword, "php");
```

Function implementation:

```
sub generateConfig {
    my($inName) = $_[0];
    my($inPass) = $_[1];
    my($inExt)  = $_[2];

    my($goodData) = 1;
    my($select)   = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM $databasesTableName WHERE name = '$inName'");
    my($path)     = $documentRoot.$inName."_config.".$inExt;
    $select->execute();

    if ($select->rows < 1 ) {
            $goodData = 0;
    }

    while ( $result = $select->fetchrow_hashref() )
    {
            my($insert) = $dbh->do("INSERT INTO $configTableName(databaseId, username, password, path)".
                                   "VALUES('$$result{'id'}', '$inName', '$inPass', '$path')");

    }

    return 1;
    }
```

Errors:

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./dbcreator.pl line 142.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./dbcreator.pl line 154.
```

Line 142:

```
        $update = $dbh->do("UPDATE ${tablename}
                        SET ${jobStatus}='${newStatus}' 
                        WHERE id = '$$result{'id'}'");
```

Line 154:

```
 print "Successfully created $$result{'databaseName'}\n";
```

The reason I think the problem comes from the function call is because if I comment out the function call, everything works great!

If anyone could help me understand what's going on, that would be great.

Thanks,

p.s. If you notice a security issue with the whole storing passwords as plain text in a database, that's going to be addressed after this is working correctly. =P

Dylan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to store a reference to the $result returned from fetchrow_hashref, as each subsequent call will overwrite that reference.

That's ok, you're not using the reference when you are calling generate_config, as you are passing data in by value.

Are you using the same $result variable in generate_config and in the calling function?  You should be using your own 'my $result' in generate_config.

```
      while ( my $result = $select->fetchrow_hashref() )
      #       ^^  #add my
```

That's all that can be said with the current snippets of code you've included.

Some cleanup:

1. When calling generate_config you are passing by value, not by reference.  This is fine.
2. you are getting an undef warning, this means you are running with 'use strict;'. Good!
3. create lexical $result within the function, via my.
4. While $$hashr{key} is valid code, $hashr->{key} is preferred.
5. you're using dbh->prepare, might as well use placeholders.

   ```
   sub generateConfig {
     my($inName, inPass, $inExt) = @_;

     my $goodData = 1;
     my $select   = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM $databasesTableName WHERE name = ?");
     my $insert   = $dbh->prepare("
                       INSERT INTO $configTableName(
                         databaseID
                         ,username
                         ,password
                       ,path) 
                       VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?)" );
     my $path     = $documentRoot . $inName . "_config." . $inExt;
     $select->execute( $inName );

     if ($select->rows < 1 ) {
           $goodData = 0;
     }

     while ( my $result = $select->fetchrow_hashref() )
     {
       insert->execute( $result->{id}, $inName, $inPass, $path );
     }

    return 1;
   ```

   }

Comment: Thank you so much. It was the fact that I'm using $result again in the generateConfig function! I completely missed this! I will also implement some of the other things you suggested. As you can probably tell, I'm new to Perl. Thanks again! Also, thanks everyone else, you're posts were helpful too!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: after reading your comment

I think that both errors have to do with your using `$$result`. If `$result` is the return value of `fetchrow_hashref`, like in:

```
$result = $select->fetchrow_hashref()
```

then the correct way to refer to its values should be:

```
 print "Successfully created " . $result{'databaseName'} . "\n";
```

and:

```
    $update = $dbh->do("UPDATE ${tablename}
                    SET ${jobStatus}='${newStatus}' 
                    WHERE id = '$result{'id'}'");
```

OLD ANSWER:

In function `generateConfig`, you can pass a reference in using this syntax:

```
generateConfig(\$result{'databaseName'},$newPassword, "php");
```

(`$$` is used to dereference a reference to a string; `\` gives you a reference to the object it is applied to).

Then, in the print statement itself, I would try:

```
 print "Successfully created $result->{'databaseName'}->{columnName}\n";
```

indeed, `fetchrow_hashref` returns a hash (not a string).

This should fix one problem.

Furthermore, you are using the variable named `$dbh` but you don't show where it is set. Is it a global variable so that you can use it in `generateConfig`? Has it been initialized when `generateConfig` is executed?

Comment: sergio,

Thanks for you quick response.

When I try using the '\' inplace of the '$' when passing $result{'databaseName'}, I get the following error (I tried this already too):

Global symbol "%result" requires explicit package name at ./dbcreator.pl line 127.

Also, $dbh is a global. But after you mentioned it, I passed it as a fourth parameter to generateConfig. Didn't seem to change anything.

Dylan

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Stack Overflow. Trying to figure out the interface...

Is there a way to respond with more room to format text properly and such?

Comment: sergio, I think you are overthinking the first part. If he wants to pass some part of the outer $result into the function he should do the same as you had him to on the inside one, `$result->{'databaseName'}`

Comment: @sergio $dbh is a commonly used variable name associated with the CPAN module DBI.pm.  `my $dbh = DBI->connect(......);` returns a database handle.  As statements are prepared to be executed, the handle is used: `my $sth = $dbh->prepare(.....); $sth->execute(...);`

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me crazy when I was running hetchrow_hashref from Oracle result set.
Turened out the column names are always returned in upper case.
So once I started referencing the colum in upper case, problem went away:
insert->execute( $result->{ID}, $inName, $inPass, $path );